# .NET Entity serialization: Load updated entities from legacy versions of files?

Tags: c#, serialization, refactoring

Here is the situation

1. I created an entity.  It has a first and last name field
2. I serialized some instances to a file
3. Now I have updated the entity.  Instead of having first and last name, I just have have a FullName field and I have removed the first and last name properties
4. I want to deserialize the instances I created in step (2) to this new version

What is the proper method to write a translator for this in C#?  Is there some class that does it?

Note:  I have previously asked a similar question but I did not phrase it the same way.  I received a very good answer on how to handle a situation where a field name changes, but I did not get an answer for how to handle this new situation.  You can view the old question here [Entities used to serialize data have changed. How can the serialized data be upgraded for the new entities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4694831/entities-used-to-serialize-data-have-changed-how-can-the-serialized-data-be-upg)

Comment: I'm planning on using DataContract serialization.  Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement ISerializable and deal with backwards compatibility in your deserialization code. In the example below, I also account for the fact that there could be older versions of the application still using the data store.

```
    public Object(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) {
        try { fullName = info.GetString("fullName"); }
        catch (SerializationException) {
            // fullName not found. Old version
            string firstName = info.GetString("firstName");
            string lastName = info.GetString("lastName");
            fullName = firstName + " " + lastName;
        }
    }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) {
        info.AddValue("fullName", fullName);
        // Deal with old version of application
        string[] splitName = fullName.Split(' ');
        info.AddValue("firstName", splitName[0]);
        info.AddValue("lastName", splitName[1]);
    }
```

The same principal can be used when implementing ISerializableSurrogate.

Comment: This makes sense.  However, I've come across ISerializationSurrogate which seems very similar.  Do you know off hand if I should be using this since I am using a DataContract?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188950.aspx.  I'm guessing this might be better since it separates the serialization code from my entities (which is likely what I want if I am dealing with multiple versions)

Comment: @i8abug Of course you could use ISerializationSurrogate instead and you are correct in that it has the advantage of separating the serialization code from your entity. The same principal as in my example could be used, though.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so using a surrogate might be the answer.  I'm still not entirely sure what a surrogate is but it seems like it gives more control for this if you are using DataContract serialization

Comment: A surrogate is a "stand in" that you use instead of the original. Instead of trying to deserialise directly into your new entity (with the `FullName` field), deserialise into a different class, one with properties that match those of your original entity. Once you have the surrogate populated, you can use C# code to convert the details to the new format.

Comment: +1 thanks - Can you check out my comment under Vendel's answer?  I'm still thinking surrogate is the way to go (and at this point, I should probably just try it) but if you know off hand if that is the "correct" way for me to do this, it would really get me off on the right track.  That interface as described in the link is almost identical to ISerializable which gives me to ability to avoid keeping a set of "stand in" classes I think.